# FutureTask call() refer object, result wrong

Tags: java, task, future

I want result is

```
jsonObject={"key":[2,2,3]}
jsonObject={"key":[2,4,3]}
jsonObject={"key":[2,4,6]}
```

but result is

```
{"key":[2,4,6]}
{"key":[2,4,6]}
{"key":[2,4,6]}
```

I dont know what's wrong.
please help.
thanks!

how to change code?
Object always is last number.

code is:

```
public class TestFutureTask {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] list = {1,2,3};
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        List<FutureTask<String>> futureTasks = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++){
            int[] list1 = list;
            list1[i] = list1[i]*2;
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("key", list1);
            futureTasks.add(new FutureTask<String>(new QueryExecutor(jsonObject)));
        }

        for(int n=0;n<futureTasks.size();n++){
            executor.submit(futureTasks.get(n));
        }

        for(int n=0;n<futureTasks.size();n++){
            try {
                System.out.println(futureTasks.get(n).get());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                executor.shutdown();
            }
        }
    }
}

class QueryExecutor implements Callable<String> {
    private JSONObject jsonObject;
    public QueryExecutor(JSONObject jsonObject){
        System.out.println("jsonObject="+jsonObject);
        this.jsonObject = jsonObject;
    }
    @Override
    public String call(){
        String result = jsonObject.toString();
        return result;
    }

}
```

I think maybe async and method Call() refer object problem.

ExecutorService and FutureTask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a reminder Arrays in Java are Objects.

Your problem is with Same Object referencing see the below snippet of the code

```
 int[] list = {1,2,3};
 int[] list1 = list;
 list1[i] = list1[i]*2;
```

when you update the reference list1 even list also gets updated because they point to the same object internally and hence the Array that is passed below to the call method in all the Furture reference is eventually the same.

try changing from

```
int[] list1 = list;
```

to

```
int[] list1 = Arrays.copyOf(list,list.length);
```

Run and see if this meets your expectations

Comment: Your Welcome. I also realized that above code would change the logic since list is not longer modified by the changes. If you want to get the same results as mentioned in the Question try changing just `jsonObject.put("key", list1);` to `jsonObject.put("key", Arrays.toString(list1));`

Answer (score 0):

```
 ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(){{add(1);add(2);add(3);}};

    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        ArrayList<Integer> list1 = list;
        list1.set((i),list1.get(i) * 2);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("key", list1.toString());
        System.out.println(list1.toString());
    }
```

replace the above code in your following code snippet:

```
int[] list = {1,2,3};
for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++){
    int[] list1 = list;
    list1[i] = list1[i]*2;
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("key", list1);
}
```

[image]